# Set an ETag on all images

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to set an ETag on all images served through apache, per Google's recommendation here: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching. Here's my .htaccess:

```
<ifModule mod_expires.c>  
    ExpiresActive On  
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 seconds"  
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"  
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"  
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"  
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"  
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"  
</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>  
    <filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">  
        Header set Cache-Control "public"
        FileETag MTime Size  
    </filesMatch> 
</IfModule>
```

For some reason, that's not working. The HTTP headers on images have cache-control set but not an ETag. The website where I'm working this is: http://bestnovapainters.com/

Some other things running on the site (might be helpful to know): Wordpress 3.8.1, PHP 5.4.1, Clouflare CDN.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you eventually got this working on your website judging by its current headers - can you please share your solution? I'm having a similar problem - the ETag header is set by my local Apache server but not by my hosting provider's Apache server even though their .htaccess files are essentially identical.